# How can I not load a JS script on a certain OS client?

Tags: php, javascript, windows-phone-8, ckeditor

I am using the WYSIWYG editor CKEditor which apparently does not get along with Windows Phone 8 at all (it breaks the entire site when kept in the head).  I'm not certain if it's an IE issue overall or Win8 specifically, but the site will be accessed via a custom corp app wrapper so suggesting an alternate browser isn't an option.  I don't really care about them losing the functionality.

Is there a simple way I can write something like this into the head in PHP?

```
if(OS == Windows Phone 8){
    //nothing
} else {
    echo "<script src=\"ckeditor/ckeditor.js\"></script>";
}
```

I'm open to any solution, but PHP is what I'm using in general.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104607/easiest-way-os-detection-with-php

Comment: another approach would be to you a conditional loader like yepnope.js and modernizr.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the user agent in PHP and include the script if it doesn't match Windows Phone 8:

```
$pattern = "/Windows\sPhone\s8/";
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(!preg_match($pattern, $user_agent))
{
    echo "<script src=\"ckeditor/ckeditor.js\"></script>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's `IEMobie 10` causing the problem you can check for that in the Useragent.

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'IEMobile/10.0') === FALSE)
    echo '<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>';
```

You could even do it in Javascript if you prefer:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile/10.0') === -1)
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>';
```

You can also use conditional comments:

```
<![if !IEMobile]> 
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<![endif]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using javascript, why not match the user agent using javascript instead of PHP? [[Credit](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/fix-ie-10-on-windows-phone-8-viewport/)]

```
if !(navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) { ...
```

*On Windows 7 phone you could target the browser [using just HTML](http://css-tricks.com/iemobile-conditional-comment/), but unfortunately Microsoft got rid of that feature with Windows Phone 7.5.