# How to detect client OS via HTTP?

Tags: http, browser, operating-system

What is the best way to detect the OS running on an HTTP client? I know that the browser's `User-Agent` may be falsified. So should I use handle of HTTP? And is there any difference between HTTP packets sent from WinXP and Win7? I only need to detect these.

Comment: If the `User-Agent` header may be falsified, so may everything else. What do you want to do with this information and how low-level a language are you working with?

Comment: I am working with ASP.NET. I need redirect Windows XP user (not depending of browser) to special page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operating System from User-Agent HTTP Header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228256/operating-system-from-user-agent-http-header)

Comment: Just Windows XP or Windows in general?

Comment: I want to detect just Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User Agent String for Windows XP is `Windows NT 5.1` or `Windows XP`.

For instance in JavaScript the necessary string is returned with:

```
function osInfo() { 
  alert(window.navigator.oscpu); 
}
// returns: "Windows NT 6.0" for example
```