# Collecting client computer and browser statistics

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, statistics

We have a web application in which user can upload files to our server. We need to find the following details of clients so that we could know our user base

1. Operating System with version
2. Browser with version

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [HttpRequest.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get the browser identifier. For information about the operation system, refer to this [SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228256/operating-system-from-user-agent-http-header)

An example from the above link:

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = Request.Browser;
 Response.Write("<p>Browser Capabilities:</p>");
 Response.Write("Type = " + bc.Type + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Name = " + bc.Browser + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Version = " + bc.Version + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Major Version = " + bc.MajorVersion + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Minor Version = " + bc.MinorVersion + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Platform = " + bc.Platform + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Is Beta = " + bc.Beta + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Is Crawler = " + bc.Crawler + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Is AOL = " + bc.AOL + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Is Win16 = " + bc.Win16 + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Is Win32 = " + bc.Win32 + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Supports Frames = " + bc.Frames + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Supports Tables = " + bc.Tables + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Supports Cookies = " + bc.Cookies + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Supports VB Script = " + bc.VBScript + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Supports JavaScript = " + bc.JavaScript + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Supports Java Applets = " + bc.JavaApplets + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Supports ActiveX Controls = " + bc.ActiveXControls + "<br>");
 Response.Write("CDF = " + bc.CDF + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

For operating system, try:

```
Request.Browser.Platform
```

For browser with version, try:

```
Request.UserAgent
```

To see what the User Agent corresponds to (if you're unsure), here's a reference http://www.user-agents.org/index.shtml?moz

Answer (score 0):

Check for

[Request.Browser property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx)